# Identify duplicates data in combined columns

Tags: mariadb-10.4

In a table there is Lang1 (First Language ID) and Lang2 (Second Language ID) that is repeating logically and I would like to keep one record and delete the other. I have encircled the entries in different colors. For instance RED Color The Languages set is (4 and 6) and there is another set that is (6 and 4 in reverse order). How can we consider this a repeating instance. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. Please have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tag your DBMS version.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please construct a fiddle with your table and some sample data (dbfiddle.uk). Also, please can you give your version(s) of MySQL and/or MariaDB!

Comment: Hi, It's MariaDB V10.4.8. Here is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=455b717db12a2bed0e7ce99772fd4e8f . There is English to French and French to English which is considered as repeating and I want to delete the one

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle; can you [edit] your question and add the link to the fiddle, so folks won't have to scan through the comments?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=18ce612433f90261bd25304286e21b01)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  lpo_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  lang_1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  lang_2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT l1_ne_l2_ck CHECK (lang_1 != lang_2)
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO test (lang_1, lang_2) VALUES
(6, 4), (4, 6), (6, 68), (68, 6), (18, 6), (6, 18), (36, 18), (18, 36), 
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), 
(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8);
```

Note that the first line of `INSERT`s contains the duplicates. Now we make use of the [`LEAST()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/least-function-in-mysql/) and [`GREATEST()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greatest-function-in-mysql/) functions as follows:

```
SELECT 
  lpo_id,
  LEAST(lang_1, lang_2), 
  GREATEST(lang_1, lang_2)
FROM test ORDER BY lpo_id;
```

Result:

```
lpo_id  LEAST(lang_1, lang_2)   GREATEST(lang_1, lang_2)
1               4                        6
2               4                        6
3               6                       68
4               6                       68
5               6                       18
6               6                       18
7              18                       36
8              18                       36
9               1                        2
...
... remaining non-duplicates snipped for brevity
...
```

So, now we add `ROW_NUMBER()` into the mix. Window functions (MariaDB documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/)) are very powerful and will repay any effort spent learning them many times over!

```
SELECT 
  lpo_id,
  LEAST(lang_1, lang_2),
  GREATEST(lang_1, lang_2),
  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(lang_1, lang_2), GREATEST(lang_1, lang_2)) AS rn
FROM test
ORDER BY lpo_id;
```

Result:

```
lpo_id  LEAST(lang_1, lang_2)   GREATEST(lang_1, lang_2)    rn
1                  4                         6               1
2                  4                         6               2
3                  6                        68               1
4                  6                        68               2
5                  6                        18               1
6                  6                        18               2
7                 18                        36               1
8                 18                        36               2
9                  1                         2               1
...
... non-dups snipped for brevity
...
```

And then we `DELETE` using the `lpo_id`s which have `rn` > 1 as follows:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE test.lpo_id IN
(
  SELECT tab.lpo_id FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      t.lpo_id, LEAST(t.lang_1, t.lang_2), GREATEST(t.lang_1, t.lang_2), 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(t.lang_1, t.lang_2), GREATEST(t.lang_1, t.lang_2)) AS rn
    FROM test t ORDER BY t.lpo_id
  ) AS tab
  WHERE tab.rn > 1
);
```

the result is a tick-mark on db<>fiddle.

Then, to check:

```
 SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY test.lpo_id;
```

Result:

```
lpo_id  lang_1  lang_2
1          6         4
3          6        68
6          6        18
7         36        18
9          1         2
10         1         3
...
... other non-dups snipped for brevity
...
```

You can use the `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions with character strings also - see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b92b3bd611ca4d4e5575e86d66b967a2) - adapted from your own one!

### Important Suggestion:

You can also change your table definition slightly so that you can never have this situation occur again by using [`CHECK`](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-check-constraint/) constraints as follows (fiddle as [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e19601f6554151c7c8291db1f4ca40d9), based on your one):

```
CREATE TABLE langue
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ipid INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  lang_1 VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT NULL,
  lang_2 VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT NULL,
  approved INTEGER NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT l1_ne_l2_ck CHECK (lang_1 != lang_2),
  CONSTRAINT l1_lt_l2_ck CHECK (lang_1 < lang_2)
);
```

So, we have two constraints - lang_1 cannot be equal to lang_2 and lang_1 must be "less" than lang_2 - the `<` operator works with character strings as well as numbers.

So, now if we try to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO langue VALUES (1, 69, 'French', 'English', 0);
```

we throw an error:

```
CONSTRAINT `l1_lt_l2_ck` failed for `db_334239447`.`langue`
```

but if we do the opposite:

```
INSERT INTO langue VALUES (1, 69, 'English', 'French', 0);
```

we are successful!

Comment: Thank you for your suggession but overall table can accept reverse order for different users. Like User A can interpret between English To French and User B can also intepret but chose languages in oposit order (French to English)

Comment: @smartpctech - then the tuple (French, English) is **NOT** the same as the tuple (English, French) - your question implied that they **were** the same!